# Mysqli fetch assoc limit size

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this simple code

```
$result = mysqli_query($sql);
$data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
return $data;
```

where `$sql is "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID < '1000'"`

there are 2000 records in my Db

My code work perfectly if I ask less then 995 records!!! but on 996 returm me null. Is there some limit?

Thanks

Comment: But what are the ID's of these 2000 rows? Did you delete a few in the 1 to 1000 range

Comment: Do you mean it returns 4 rows containing null values?

Comment: Sounds like there are only 996 records with `id < 1000`. You probably deleted a few, so there are gaps in the ID sequence.'

Comment: Also the code you show us will return only 1 row?

Comment: There's no limit to the number of rows that can be returned.

Comment: The mysqli_fetch_assoc() function fetches a result row as an associative array,not the entire rows in results

Comment: `$result = mysqli_query($sql);` you realize that that requires a db connection be passed as the first argument. Then `WHERE ID < '1000'` you need to remove the quotes for it. I hope (*spero*) that column isn't a varchar.

Comment: Woops missed that completely, but that cannot be the real code I am guessing @Fred-ii- as it only returns one row anyway

Comment: This code is so imcomplete that I can't imagine what the poster wants to do.  He's using mysqli commands but the format is in mysql.  He's saying he can get 995 rows but the code above will only fetch 1 row, and the first one each time.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Hard to say really and the schema is unknown.

Comment: *"dove il OP"* in all this? *lol!* Post your db schema and sample data.

Comment: For example if I try through PhpMyAdmin  SQL this code: SELECT * FROM table WHERE '1' the database show me all the 2000 records, but if  I use the SAME code into php script the result is null. Why in your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some limit?

No. There is no limit associated with mysqli_fetch_assoc(). It will always return a row if a query returned it.

If `$data` is null, then it means that your query returned no rows.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change the query result row limit, or remove the limit entirely.

Go to Edit → Preferences → SQL Editor (tab).

If you can't find Query Results, go to SQL Queries(tab) instead.

Locate the Query Results section and untick the Limit Rows checkbox
Click OK.

Re-run your query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Viral, what you mean when you say "Go to Edit". I use PhpMyadmin